# vim slows down when using fold-expr

Tags: vim, folding, code-folding

I'm trying to create a simple, fast folding method for large markdown files. I'm using the `fold-expr` method in vim. For example, if I wanted to start folds on `H1` and `H2` markdown entries, my vimscript code is:

```
function! MarkdownLevel() 
    if getline(v:lnum) =~ '^# '
        " begin a fold of level one here 
        return ">1" 
    elseif getline(v:lnum) =~ '^## ' 
        " begin a fold of level two 
        return ">2" 
    else
        return "=" 
    endif 
endfunction
```

This works perfectly, and I get nested folds. However, when I have a large markdown file, vim slows down considerably. This is unsurprising and is, in fact, indicated in the fold-expr help in vim. It's because the `=` sign tells vim to scan backwards in the file until the first line with an *explicitly defined* foldlevel can be found; this could be thousands of lines away.

I tried to replace the last line with

```
   else
      " set foldlevel to foldlevel of previous line
      return foldlevel(v:lnum-1)
   endif
```

But this doesn't work as expected. Does anyone know how to fix this? It's clear I'm not understanding how the foldlevel function works, or how the folding algorithm in vim is implemented.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to fix the slowdown and learned somethings about how `fold-expr` works in vim. I tested the performance issues on a 3000 line md file.

I was relying on the following automatic folding functionality that `fold-expr` is supposed to have: it starts a fold if foldlevel of the current line is smaller than the foldlevel of the next. It ends a fold if the foldlevel of the current line is larger than the foldlevel of the next. Turns out that this does not work as intended, as far as I can tell.

What worked was to explicitly tell vim that a fold starts *here* using `return ">1"`, where `1` is replaced by the appropriate number.

After learning how to profile vim scripts from @PeterRinker, I figured out that the `return "="` statement was being evaluated many, many times when I was editing line (for example) 3000.

This was my fix: if the foldlevel of the current line does not fall into any of the heading types *and* the foldlevel of the previous line has already been defined, the current line should just inherit the foldlevel of the previous line. This is an obvious solution, but it *does not work* if I used `return "1"` instead of `return ">1"` above. It needs the `return "="` statement on the first pass to figure out the foldlevel.

So my startup times are a little big (about 1 second) for a 3000 line file, but now editing is very smooth. The following is the finished, simplistic code. Other more elaborate markdown projects do not have this useful simplification.

```
function! MarkdownLevel()
    let theline = getline(v:lnum)
    let nextline = getline(v:lnum+1)
    if theline =~ '^# ' 
        " begin a fold of level one here
            return ">1"
    elseif theline =~ '^## ' 
        " begin a fold of level two here
            return ">2"
    elseif theline =~ '^### ' 
        " begin a fold of level three here
            return ">3"
    elseif nextline =~ '^===*'
        " elseif the next line starts with at least two ==
        return ">1"
    elseif nextline =~ '^---*'
        " elseif the line ends with at least two --
        return ">2"
    elseif foldlevel(v:lnum-1) != "-1" 
        return foldlevel(v:lnum-1)
    else
        return "="
    endif
end
```

Comment: I have a around 3000 line file that hit the "=" part a lot, which makes editing the file very very slow. This method saved my day, it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about using Drew Nelstrom's [vim-markdown-folding](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding) plugin?

You may also want to look that the Vimcast episode: [Profiling Vimscript performance](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/profiling-vimscript-performance/). This episode actually talks about folding markdown.

**Cautionary thoughts**

I can not be for certain because I have not profiled your code (and you should really profile your code), but as the fold expression gets called on every line every time things get redrawn it can be very taxing on Vim. Some guesses:

- Using relative fold expressions like `=` means we need to compute the previous line so as you can imagine this can become problematic. Try and use exact depths without computing other lines if you can.
- You are using `getline()` twice in your function needlessly
- Some files are just going to cause problems accept this fact and disable folding via `zi`

Comment: I profiled it, and the problem is the `return "="` . It gets called very often, and takes a fair bit of time to run. I can't seem to get an alternative running with `return foldlevel(v:lnum-1)`. I wonder if there is a way around this.

Comment: I think I fixed it. I'd appreciate any feedback, comments.

Answer (score 0):

That is to be expected, since Vim has to compute your expression a lot for every line. This is also mentioned in the help below `:h fold-expr`

```
Note: Since the expression has to be evaluated for every line,
this fold method can be very slow!

Try to avoid the "=", "a" and "s" return values, since Vim often
has to search backwards for a line for which the fold level is
defined.  This can be slow.
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of that; it's stated in my post. I'm trying to find an alternative to the `=` sign.